# Сравнить значения словаря из списка и при совпадении выдать ключ из словаря

Tags: python-3.x, list, словари, compare

```
dictionary = {'key': 'val', 'key2': 'val2'} 
list = ["val", "val2", "val3"]
```

Необходимо сравнить значения словаря и списка и при совпадении выдать ключ из словаря.

Comment: В чем у вас проблема? И по какому принципу устанавливается связь между ключом словаря и элементом списка?

Comment: Поправьте заголовок или тело вопроса -- они полностью противоположные

Comment: mkkik, ну собственно проблема в самом написании (

Comment: mkkik  на счет принципа связи между ключом словаря и элемента списка меня тоже интересует, может связь нельзя выполнить

Comment: @rrron, а что вам не так в моем коде?  просто, любопытно :) можно иначе - https://eval.in/918348

Comment: @splash58 код похож на то что надо, но к сожалению ничего не выдает (

Comment: ну, что-от на модельных данных он выдает, судя по eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [24]: dictionary = {'key': 'val', 'key2': 'val2'}

In [25]: lst = ["val", "val2", "val3"]

In [26]: reversed_dict = {x: y for y, x in dictionary.items()}

In [27]: result = [reversed_dict[x] for x in list(set(dictionary.values()) & set(lst))]

In [28]: result
Out[28]: ['key', 'key2']
```

Но вариант в ответе ранее лучше и проще :)

Еще вариант:

```
In [35]: list(filter(lambda x: dictionary[x] in lst, dictionary))
Out[35]: ['key', 'key2']
```

Comment: Второй вариант подошел, супер! )

Answer (score 1):

я не умею про питон, но что-то такое должно работать, может, неэффективно

```
for i in dictionary :
   for j in list :
      if  j == dictionary[i] :
         print(i)
```

И если это не учебное задание, то однострочно. Впрочем,  это есть по ссылке в комменте

```
print([k for k,v in dictionary.items() if list.count(v)])
```

Или даже по мотивам ответа @Alban

```
print([k for k,v in dictionary.items() if v in list])
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!